# Update Quartz.net cron trigger not to execute on a particular date/dates for daily trigger.

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have cron trigger which fire daily at particular time of the day, I have to update that trigger so that i don't want that trigger to be executes on particular date.

eg. I have trigger which execute daily on each day, I have to pass a date (31Oct2017)  On this date this trigger should not execute.

I tried below code

```
var calendar = SCSScheduler.Scheduler.GetCalendar(id);
 CronCalendar cronCal = new CronCalendar(calendar,cronExceptionSchedule);
                SCSScheduler.Scheduler.AddCalendar(id, cronCal, true, true);
   var newTrigger = tb.WithCronSchedule(cronSchedule)
                    .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                    .ForJob(id)
                    .ModifiedByCalendar(id)
                    .Build();

            SCSScheduler.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(key, newTrigger);
```

I do not find any method to update calendar to not to execute job for this particular date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `HolidayCalendar` class, which is used to exclude whole days from the triggers you create.

This is actually quite well described in the [documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html) (code for quartz 3.0beta1):

```
HolidayCalendar cal = new HolidayCalendar();
cal.AddExcludedDate(new DateTime(2017, 10, 31));

await sched.AddCalendar("myHolidays", cal, false, false);

ITrigger t = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger")
    .ForJob("myJob")
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(9, 30)) // execute job daily at 9:30
    .ModifiedByCalendar("myHolidays") // but not on holidays
    .Build();
```